# How do you integrate Cucumber/Jasmine in Hybris v4.8.7 Ecommerce Suite?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, cucumber, sap-commerce-cloud

I am looking to integrate Unit Testing i.e. Jasmine/Cucumber to help to my development. I know its possible but require step-by-step guide to how to do this on Hybris v4.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source a detailed step by step guide is probably the Hybris documentation.

Extending hybris is a matter of building Hybris plugins. They are build like any other Java project.

The answer to your question is therefore a matter of which build tool you are using to build your extensions.

If you build using Maven, all you have to do is to add the tests to the proper location and add a dependency to a unit testing framework.

```
src/test/java/...your.package.../FooTest.java
```

This is unfortunately as detailed as you can get without sharing more details.

Comment: We use ANT as our build tool. I was not clear on what type of unit testing. I want to use unit testing for Front-end BDD ie integrate Jasmine/Cucumber.